# the definition of regular fibers of a morphism $A\to B$ given in context of $B$ tensor k is the same as given by inverse image

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Since fiber of the element $y$ in the set $Y$ under a map $f \colon X \to Y$ is the inverse image of the singleton $\{y\}$ under $f$. An other definition of fibers given in terms of tensor product (some thing like in definition 15.37 at http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07BY).

More precisely the definition which we see mostly of geometrically regular fibers can also be explained in terms of inverse image of a map?? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The inverse image of a singletion is just the set-theoretic fibre. This however is not a very strong tool to understand maps in algebraic geometry.

Comment: I believe they are related some how. As both are fibers so I think they are same. I also studied in the book "Topics in m-adic Completions" at first page of chapter 12. Look here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2F978-3-642-88501-3_12/lookinside/000.png but I did not understand it completely. Your suggestions will be highly acknowledged.